# puppetlabs-java module unable to install

Tags: java, ubuntu, module, puppet

Using puppetlabs-java to install Java version 1.7.0_80 on Ubuntu.

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/java

My site.pp is

```
class { 'java':
        package  => "java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel",
        version => "1.7.0_80"
   }
```

Is my class definition proper? getting error as below:

```
Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel=1.7.0_80' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel'
Wrapped exception:
 Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel=1.7.0_80' returned 100: Reading package lists...
```

Comment: The installation `java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel` with `apt-get` fails. Did you do a `apt-get update` and tried to install the package yourself and are you absolutley sure that the package is provided by one of your repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Im trying to install it using puppet module. So thought all the steps are added in it. Module usage says just giving version and package it works.

Comment: All "puppet" can do is determining the platform and invoking the local packet manager to install the version you want. However, it failed in this case in the step of doing the `apt-get update` and/or `apt-get install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel`. Notice that on https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/java it is explicitly stated "This module cannot guarantee installation of Java versions that are not available on platform repositories.[..]Oracle Java packages are not included in Debian 7 and Ubuntu 12.04/14.04 repositories. To install Java on those systems, you'll need to package Oracle JDK/JRE"

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thank you !! 

How to package  Oracle JDK/JRE.

Comment: The above link is where I quoted that text from (Seciton "Limitations"). It is followed by a link to https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage .